# spring with oracle DB - "java.sql.SQLException - invalid username/password; logon denied"

Tags: java, database, spring, oracle

I am using spring-data with hibernate and I want to use oracle (Express Edition) as my database. In order to manage my dependencies I am using gradle.

To use oracle as my database I am using ojdbc6 (11.0.2.0.2) which I installed in my local maven repository. I am also using jdk 1.8 (just if someone thinks the ojdbc-version could possibly be not compatible with the jdk-version).

I installed ojdbc6 with this command:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=Downloads\Programmieren\OJDBC\ojdbc6.jar -DgroupId=com.oracle -DartifactId=ojdbc6 -Dversion=11.2.0.2.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

I created the user "JAVAUSER" with the password "PASSWORD". It's uppercase because I am using Oracle10g which sends its data always uppercase but oracle11g (11.0.2.0 which I use) is case sensitive (so everything has to be created uppercase).

To the user "JAVAUSER" I gave the rights sysdba and dba - so this account should be able to do everything.

```
CREATE USER JAVAUSER identified by PASSWORD;
grant connect to JAVAUSER;
grant all privileges to JAVAUSER;
grant dba to JAVAUSER;
grant sysdba to JAVAUSER;
```

I am able to create a session with sql-developer.

This is my application.properties-file:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
spring.datasource.data-username=JAVAUSER
spring.datasource.data-password=PASSWORD
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.data.rest.base-path=/api
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
server.port=8090
```

This is my build.gradle-file:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.9.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        mavenLocal()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

group = 'com.chantal'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    mavenLocal()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest')
    compile('org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    //compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    //compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('com.oracle:ojdbc6:11.2.0.2.0')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
    testCompile('org.springframework.restdocs:spring-restdocs-mockmvc')
    testCompile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-test')
}

test {
    testLogging.showStandardStreams = true
}
```

this is the error-output:

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:389) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:382) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.processError(T4CTTIfun.java:573) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:431) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:366) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOAUTH(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:752) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:366) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:536) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:228) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:521) ~[ojdbc6-11.2.0.2.0.jar:11.2.0.2.0]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:310) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:203) ~[tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:735) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:667) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:482) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.getConnection(DataSourceProxy.java:131) [tomcat-jdbc-8.5.23.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:33) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.DatabaseExporter.<init>(DatabaseExporter.java:35) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.execute(SchemaExport.java:425) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:361) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaExport.create(SchemaExport.java:350) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:469) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) [hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60) [spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) [spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) [spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) [spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) [spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.chantal.ChantalApplication.main(ChantalApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
```

Comment: spring.datasource.data-username? What does [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#common-application-properties) say about this property? What does [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-connect-to-production-database) say about properties to define a data source?

Comment: Or, to put it another way, did you carefully scan the template linked by @JBNizet for ALL occurrences of the strings `username` and `password`?

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, no I didn't - I was said that this is the way to do it (I learned it that way) so I didn't think that this could be the problem. JBNizet - please post an answer (if you want) so I can upvote and accept it.

Comment: And yes - Now I know where what the problem was - thank you indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I set the

```
# User of the database to execute DML scripts (if different).
spring.datasource.data-username=
# Password of the database to execute DML scripts (if different). 
spring.datasource.data-password=
```

instead of

```
spring.datasource.username =
spring.datasource.password =
```

which is the login user.